# question regarding csv format?

Tags: mysql, csv

> CSV format cannot be used for importing text files to a database unless the table for the data is already defined in the database.

is this true or false?

Comment: Please tag this question with the RDBMS that you are using. Thanks.

Comment: In the case of an RDBMS this is certainly true.

Comment: It won't hurt to simply try it.

Comment: "Is this true or false"? Neither. Cardboard boxes cannot be used to load groceries into a car unless the trunk is already open. Is this true or false?

Answer (score -1):

For MS SQL Server.
False: You can use the Import Data Wizard to map your columns in the CSV file to columns in the Table that the Wizard will create when you run it.

Comment: Technically the table is created before the file is imported, as would be shown in the SSIS task flow generated by the wizard.  I was thinking `FileTable` maybe but then I guess the `FileTable` is the table that needs to be already defined.  Really, the question sounds like it's off a quiz.

Comment: The user is asking about MySQL not SQL Server